# Adding box-shadow on a single nav item

Tags: html, css

I am making my own website and for the menu, I am having a hard time. This is how menu looks like now.

[image]

Everything is perfect except one thing! I am trying to add box-shadow to "Blog" menu item and if you zoom-in, you'll see box-shadow on the left side of "Blog" and on top of it, as well. But it doesn't appear on the right side. Looks like "About" is overlapping.

There is no problem in box-shadow code. But, here it is:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
```

Here is the HTML file:

```css
    footer{
      bottom: 0;
      // height: 100px;
      left: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
    
      nav.main{}
    
      nav.main ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
      }
    
      nav.main ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        line-height: 1;
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
        text-align: center;
        width: 20%;
      }
    
      nav.main ul li span{
        display: block;
        font-size: 5rem;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
      }
    
      nav.main ul li a{
        color: #2D2D2D;
        display: block;
        font-size: 2rem;
        padding: 2rem;
      }
    
      nav.main ul li a.highlight{
        background-color: #ACFF32;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
    
        border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        margin-top: -1.5rem;
        padding-top: 3.5rem;
      }
    }
```

```html
<footer>
      <nav class="main">
        <ul>
          <li style="background: #33A2FF;">
            <a href="#">
              <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xec02;" class="icon icon-briefcase"></span>
              PROJECTS
            </a>
          </li>
          <li style="background: #22E886;">
            <a href="#">
              <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe92e;" class="icon icon-bucket"></span>
              DESIGNS
            </a>
          </li>
          <li style="background: #ACFF32;">
            <a href="#" class="highlight">
              <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe91c;" class="icon icon-pen"></span>
              BLOG
            </a>
          </li>
          <li style="background: #E8BA22;">
            <a href="#">
              <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xec27;" class="icon icon-brain"></span>
              ABOUT
            </a>
          </li>
          <li style="background: #FF6F25;">
            <a href="#">
              <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xea35;" class="icon icon-mailbox"></span>
              CONTACT
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </footer>
```

One more thing and this is important to give you some idea. If I add background to nav tag and remove all the colours on menu items, box shadow will work. So, defining colours separately is causing problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);

Comment: @Reddy Nope, it doesn't work. But as I said, the problem is not with box-shadow. I checked. About sections is overlapping shadow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the z-index of the active tab higher than the others, so the drop shadow stays on top:

So add this to `nav.main ul li a.highlight` :

```
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you very much. I also added z-index but it didn't work out. So, looks like I also had to add `position: relative` but could you tell me what is the purpose of that there?

Comment: Whenever you want to use z-index property on an element, you must define the position property as well, otherwise defining z-index will have no effect. If an element doesn't have the position property defined already (such as in this case) then you can just use "position: relative" since that is the default. You're welcome!

Comment: Here is what I noted above, documented: "z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)." http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp